# How to verify a stationary point is attractive?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

In the papers about fixed point method or gradient method in optimization problems, I often see the authors mention that the objective function has an attractive stationary point at the global minimum. I want to known, what does it mean "attractive" and how to prove a stationary is attractive or is not attractive?

Comment: It means that if you follow gradient descent in a small enough neighbourhood, then you will surely end up at the stationary point i.e. it attracts points nearby it.

Comment: Hessian is positive definite, so you are at the bottom of a bowl, and the gradient points the marble to the bottom.